Sliding glass door temporary seal
In the photo you can see that below the tension rod the sliding glass door is disconnected from the glass due to the doggy door being in place. This is making the home very cold as cold air is seeping through from the outside due to the sliding glass doors no longer lining up on where they should be sealed. Does this community have any recommendations to help temporarily seal gap? We use the door infrequently and we do rent so it cannot be a permanent solution. Something easy to take on and off



Some simple adhesive weather stripping might do the trick, but that's not really something you'd put on and take off repeatedly. Is that an absolute requirement? It looks like the door would still slide with weather stripping, but not be able to close completely.

We still do enter the backyard about once or twice a week to mow the grass/as a safety item if we needed to get out there we’d want the ability to do so.

Right, my question is if it's OK if the door can still slide part way with the fix in place, or if the door needs to shut fully which would require removing the fix.

Oh, you mean if we were to remove the doggy door the door will not shut fully with the temporary fix you’re proposing? If that’s the case that would be fine as long as the “fix” can be removed without damage giving we are renting

Does the door seal if the doggie door is removed?  I would expect it to be an air leak no matter what you do to the rest of the door. (Which is one of the reasons I didn't put in a cat door to my enclosed porch; I'd want to come up with one that prevented airflow when the cat wasn't using it.)

Idea 1:
Get yourself a roll of felt or fleece as wide as the door gap is high. Roll it uniformly until it just fits snugly in the gap. Secure the roll edge with double-sided tape or stitches or hot glue.
It should roll with the door when you open it and (mostly) stay in place when you close it.
Idea 2:
Cut a strip of flexible rubber. It should be as wide as the gap plus the door thickness. Attach it to the door edge with double-sided foam tape so it's just snug against the outer glass pane.
